# fork() and wait() in a Shell program

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I'm new to C programming, and I'm trying to make a "shell", using `fork()` to make child-processes and `execvp` to send in commands. My goal is to make my program able to run processes both concurrently, and by waiting.

For example, if I type `emacs test.sml`, I would like my shell to open emacs with this file, and wait for the user to end emacs. (create a new child, and then the parent wait for the child to finish)

However, if I type `emacs test.sml &`, then I would like my shell to open emacs, and then be ready for a new command, even if the user keeps emacs open. (create a new child, and then the parent is ready for new input).

The code I've written so far does this, but it seems like the `wait()` only works on the first child. If I do the following:

1. -> `emacs`

   - the parent waits (as desired)
2. -> `emacs &`

   - the parent does not wait (as desired)
3. -> `emacs`

   - the parent does not wait (undesired).

This is my main code. Setup fetches the user input, but its not relevant here:

```
int main(void)
{
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE];
    int background;
    char *args[MAX_LINE/+1];

    while(1) {
        background = 0;

        int mainpid = getpid();
        printf("My PID is %d\n",mainpid);
        printf(" COMMAND->\n");
        setup(inputBuffer,args,&background);

        pid_t pid; //Setting the PID
        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        }
        //background is 1 if the command ends with &
        if(background == 1)
        {
            if(pid==0)
            {
                printf("Child should run concurrently with parent\n");
                int pid = getpid();
                int ppid = getppid();
                printf("Child PID %d\n", pid);
                printf("Child PPID %d\n", ppid);
                execvp(inputBuffer, args);
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Parent not waiting\n");
                int pid = getpid();
                printf("Parent PID %d\n", pid);
            }
        }
        else if(background != 1)
        {
            if(pid==0)
            {
                printf("Child running and parent waiting\n");
                int pid = getpid();
                int ppid = getppid();
                printf("Child PID %d\n", pid);
                printf("Child PPID %d\n", ppid);
                execvp(inputBuffer, args);
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Parent WAIT\n");
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Parent done waiting\n");
                int pid = getpid();
                printf("Parent PID %d\n", pid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: shell design is a huge subject. I would recommend you get the source for bash (for example) and ascertain how they do it.

Comment: This is a fairly complex task. if you fork a new process you must run a shell and set up the environment. At the command line type 'set' and you can see all the stuff that's in your environment.

Comment: You should take a look at the return value of `wait` to find out whether it is returning because the child exited, or with an error code.

Comment: For this case, see: [The Unix Programming Environment](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/upe/). If you do not want to buy the book for this one case, at least check out the example code.

Comment: Maybe `setup` function is relevant. Are you sure you're not leaving `background` variable with value 1 once set the first time? Can you sahre `setup` func?

Comment: Minimally, you can not get the result you want by passing `NULL` to wait. See [wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)

Comment: @PauloBu Yes, background is set to 0 every time the setup returns. I did a printf and checked it out now.

Comment: Your original title referred to `Fork()` and `Wait()`, which do not exist; C is case-sensitive.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to print `Child Completed` if `execvp` returns, since `execvp` will only return if there is a failure and the child has not run at all.

Comment: What would happen if you change `wait(NULL)` for `waitpid(pid, NULL, NULL)`? `pid` being the son's `pid`?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Its not actually a shell - its just a commandpromt that is using execvp to execute commands.

Comment: @PauloBu Dosen't seem to work, sadly :/

Comment: You are probably misinterpreting the results.  Case (1) works.  Case (2) is not only not waited (and later repeaped by `waitpid` when it finishes) but it will exist until it is.  Since you don't wait on any particular pid, when case (3) comes along you actually immediately reap #(2).

Comment: @Duck that's what I thought and suggest to wait for specific `pid` in my comment but didn't seemed to work :(

Comment: @Paulo Bu - I think that's it.  OP needs to confirm it for himself.

Comment: @Duck I did try it, but with no luck. Maybe the 'pid' I got was wrong. Can you please let me know how I should fetch the sons pid and use it in waitpid() at the parent?

Comment: @Jectson the `pid` you should wait for is the `fork`'s return value on the parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a process in background, without waiting, sometime later it may (will) die.  At that point, you may be waiting for another process started synchronously.

You should call `wait()` or `waitpid()` in a loop, looking for the PID of the process you just started, and cleaning up other zombie processes:

```
int status;
int corpse;

while ((corpse = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) > 0 && corpse != new_pid)
    ...process the death of 'corpse' with exit status 'status'...
```

The processing in the body of the loop might be as trivial as a semi-colon; it might remove the corpse from the list of processes running in the background (which might, perhaps, otherwise be bringable into the foreground), etc.  Although you could specify the `new_pid` as the first argument to `waitpid()`, that would leave you with other processes as zombies when you don't need to do so.  And at some point, you have to clean up zombies — when better than while you're waiting for something else to finish?  You could use `wait()` instead:

```
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0 && corpse != new_pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

execvp() may be failing.If it fails, it may appear that parent is not waiting

Please try changing this

```
execvp(inputBuffer, args);
exit(1);
```

to

```
if(execvp(inputBuffer, args)<0)
{
    printf("\n execvp failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

and see